# How to install PyTorch==1.12.1 with cudatoolkit==11.4?

Tags: pytorch

The official [installation page of PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/) excludes the `torch==1.12.1`, `cudatoolkit=11.4` option. How can I install it?

Alternatively, can I just install `torch==1.12.1` with `cudatoolkit=11.3` instead (which was present on the page)? Will it causing any harm to speed or performance?

Comment: You can install Pytorch 1.12.1 without specifying the CUDA dependency.

Comment: Although I had to remove the existing version of torch, torchvision, and torchaudio, @YashKumarAtri's answer worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, no harm. they are compatible.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).